# JS & DOM query - is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, dom

My console is returning a blank when I try to access input value of a text form by its element Id as a submit event. However, the submit event (console.log(e)) is running as expected.

I have looked and re-looked but can't see anything amiss. Where am I going wrong?

Here is my code:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("customer-name-button")
let form = document.getElementById("customer-name")

form.addEventListener('submit', submitName)
btn.addEventListener('click', clearForm)

function submitName(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let customerName = document.getElementById("customer")
  console.log(customerName.value)
  console.log(e)
}

function clearForm() {
  return form.reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="customer-name">
  <input type="text" name="customer" id="customer" placeholder="Please tell us your firstname">
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="customer-name-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You have two handlers for the button, one clears the form, removing the control's value, the other logs the control's value. I would not expect that to work.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks a million that resolves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form gets cleared via `clearForm()` before being submitted.